# cannot delete an empty folder in "root"

Tags: 14.04, files, delete

I created an empty "FTP" folder whilst setting up an ftp prog on kubuntu 14.04. I wish to delete the empty folder "ftp" in my root but having used the terminal command rm I get the answer that the file cannot be deleted since it is a "directory"?  I am in root as su so can't see why I can't delete this?  Obviously I have tried deleting the file in the GUI by right click etc. but there is no ability to....any ideas?  Many thanks

Comment: Please always include the actual command and error you receive when asking about notices from command line. It will take away any guessing. If below is not an answer to your question leave a comment below this one.

Comment: You can remove an *empty* directory using `rmdir` e.g. `rmdir ftp`

Answer (score 1):

Directories need to be removed with the option "-r". Example:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir tmp1 
rm -r tmp1
```

works.

Deleting a directy without the "-r" assumes you want to delete a file. Example:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir tmp1
rm tmp1
rm: cannot remove ‘tmp1’: Is a directory
rm -r tmp1
```

Comment: If it works dont forget to upvote and/or accept it if you like :-)